# Date saving in oracle not working for ISO 8601 standard

Tags: java, java-time

I been trying to save date with offset in the oracle DB, I manage to find the equivalent data type for timestamp with timezone offset.

I am trying to persist this to DB. I am receiving these dates from the UI (Expected format is ISO- 8601 compliant). I have following code. POJO Contains two fields .

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
private OffsetDateTime offSetDateTime;
```

DTO has the same fields with same data type but having `@JsonFormat` annotation as shown below:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ")
private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ")
private OffsetDateTime offSetDateTime;
```

Date that I am passing from the Postman is as follows:

```
{
   "zonedDateTime"  : "2011-07-04T17:19:56.235+07:00",
   "offSetDateTime" : "2011-07-04T17:19:56.235+07:00"
}
```

What gets saved in the DB is as follows:

04-JUL-11 03.49.56.235000000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA 
04-JUL-11 03.49.56.235000000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA

I want to save the above passed JSON date with same format in Database i.e. in this way '2011-07-04T17:19:56.235+07:00' and want to retrieve it with same timezone format.

Can anyone please help?

P.S I am using oracle 12 DB. How can I achieve this using Java?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: but timestamp is not saved with format; it is just displayed using a format. If you need the format saved, it must be saved as text. The format used for display is set in the session or tool used for that

Comment: okay, but in that case I lose the time-zone value as well, how can I store the offset then? either I store it as a string or store offset separately and convert it ?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle stores dates and timestamps in its own internal formats. You're just seeing how your client is choosing to display them (probably using NLS session settings). If you want to see the value in a specific format then you need to convert it to a string; with a CTE for your sample value:

```
with your_table (zonedDateTime) as (
  select to_timestamp_tz('04-JUL-11 03.49.56.235000000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF9 AM TZR')
  from dual
)
select zonedDateTime as session_format,
  to_char(zonedDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') as iso_format
from your_table;

SESSION_FORMAT                                ISO_FORMAT                         
--------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------
04-JUL-11 03:49:56.235000000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA 2011-07-04T15:49:56.235+05:30
```

The time zone seems to be converted as part of your save process, possibly implicitly from a difference between the client and server time zones when the insert is performed; but it's the same point in time.

You can convert back to a specific time zone offset as part of that query:

```
select zonedDateTime as session_format,
  to_char(zonedDateTime at time zone '+07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') as iso_format
from your_table;

SESSION_FORMAT                                ISO_FORMAT                         
--------------------------------------------- -----------------------------------
04-JUL-11 03:49:56.235000000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA 2011-07-04T17:19:56.235+07:00
```

... although you probably want to use a time zone region name rather than a fixed offset.

If you're pulling the data back into whatever application populated it, you might also want to consider querying it as its original data type rather than as a string, and then format it for display/output/onward-JSON-journey from the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

As others mention above, the date is being stored correctly (in an internal format that has the UDT timestamp plus a timezone), but your client is displaying this date in its default format.

If you need to retrieve the value in format of your choosing, regardless of client, you need to write your SELECT statement using the TO_CHAR function, with the appropriate date format.

See use of TO_CHAR here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm

See date formats here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924